# If orbot is on but orweb doesnt connect are my other apps still secure?

Tags: orbot

Im having trouble connecting to orweb even though my orbot says im connected to tor am i still secure? I also wanted to know if orbot secures other apps i have downloaded on my android phone

Answer (score 1):

Orweb is only concerned with the browser part, If orbot is on make sure that you've selected the 'Apps' option to pass the applications traffic through tor. From the additional setting you can manually select the applications list. And yes root is only needed if you want transparent proxy.

[image: The second option]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't trust other apps to be safe just because you are using Orbot. you should be able to select the Check Browser option in Orbot to see if Orweb is working through Orbot but if you want to stay safe don't go thinking your other apps are safe because they are probably not.
un-install Orbot, orweb etc and get the latest stable version and install that then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device has been rooted and you have checked the app you want to protect using orbot that's enough final check make sure your orbot is running and having a key symbol at the top left corner of your device.

Comment: How does rooting the device help? Please elaborate on what benefits this may give to answer the question.